# jQuery Endless page with will_paginate not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, will-paginate

I'm trying to implement the endless page functionality shown in Railscasts episode 114. The pagination works great but the endless page functionality doesn't trigger at all. I don't see any errors; just the pagination as if I didn't add the endless page javascript. My code:

activities controller

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map {|u| u.id}).page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
    @post = current_user.posts.build

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

activities.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Loading more activities...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#activities').append('<%= j render ('shared/activities') %>');
<% if @activities.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate('shared/activities') %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 1 %>
```

shared/_activities.html.erb

```
<div class="activities">
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
<code>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @activities %>
</div>
```

The issue must be with the javascript but I can't figure it out. Any ideas as to what could be causing the issue?

Thanks!
-b

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it withOUT an "index.js.erb" file in Rails 4. Just add this coffeescript:

```
$(window).on 'scroll', ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    @url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
      $('.pagination').remove()
      $('#articles').append('<div>')
      $('#articles div').last().load @url+' #articles', ->
          if $('.next_page.disabled').length
            $('.pagination').remove()
```

This loads the next page then uses the pagination on the newly loaded page until there are no more next pages. Just replace "#articles" with the id of your container in the script. Skip the index.js.erb and respond_to jazz.

Answer (score 0):

here are the relevant files from my code where I have endless page working with pagination.  Hopefully you can figure out your specific solution from the below:

My index.js.erb file

```
 $('.carousel').append("<%= j render ('shared/recentlyadded') %>");
<% if @recently_added_video.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith("<%= j will_paginate(@recently_added_video) %>");
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

My index.html.erb file

```
  <div class="carousel"><%= render partial: 'shared/recentlyadded' %></div>
  <%= will_paginate @recently_added_video %>
```

My _recentlyadded.html.erb file

```
 <ul class="jcarousel-skin-recent">
    <% @recently_added_video.each do |v| %>
      <li>
      <code>
      </li>
    <% end %> 
  </ul> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.jcarousel-skin-recent').jcarousel({
            wrap:'both',
            animation:'slow'
        });
    });
</script>
```

My javascript file

```
jQuery ->

  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 225
        $('.pagination').text("...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```