# SyntaxError: missing operand jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement an endless_pagination script described in the following Stackoverflow question:

[jQuery Endless page with will_paginate not working in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749959/jquery-endless-page-with-will-paginate-not-working-in-rails)

However, I get a syntax error in the error console in Firefox with the following javascript file:

```
jQuery ->

  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 225
        $('.pagination').text("...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

It seems to error on the first line. What is wrong with the syntax above?

Thanks!

EDIT: As Jeff pointed out, I misunderstood the solution to the linked question. Above code is really the output. Here is what is now in my activities.js.erb file:

```
 $('.carousel').append("<%= j render ('shared/activities') %>");
<% if @activities.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith("<%= j will_paginate(@activities) %>");
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

I don't get any errors at all but the endless pagination does not work.

Comment: That looks like coffee script it would help to see the compiled javascript. That is what is actually running in the browser.

Comment: What is the error traced in the console? Have you correctly included jQuery?

Comment: Code works in jsfiddle, are you sure you included jquery?

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the help so far. I think I misunderstood how the guy created the solution in the question I linked above. Jeff was right..I'm not supposed to include that javascript in my files..that's actually the output. I'm very new to Javascript so I'm struggling to understand what goes in my javascript. Updated question